# How to open Vite local server in a specific browser in an incognito tab?

Tags: npm, vite

I want to open my Sveltekit project in Microsoft Edge(dev) browser in inprivate/incognito tab instead of in normal tab.

for example, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe" --inprivate`

Any settings to set in `vite.config.js` file? Is there any system wide environment variable I can set?

(Found ZERO information regarding this in vite docs).

Answer (score 1):

### Open in a specific browser in a normal tab :

```
//vite.config.js file.

server: 
{
  open: 
    process.env.BROWSER='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Dev\\Application\\msedge.exe'
}
```

---

### Open in a specific browser in an incognito/inprivate tab :

At the time of writing, Vite doesn't support passing arguments in `process.env.BROWSER` in `server.open` in `vite.config.js` file - see [Vite Issue 9557](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9557)

So at the moment, editing `package.json` is the only solution - the following works

```
//package.json file.
 
//both of the default script-shell and shell are set to PowerShell.

"scripts": 
{
    "dev": "& 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Dev\\Application\\msedge.exe' --inprivate 127.0.0.1:5173  && vite"
}
```

Comment: in the last version, they added an option for  **incognito**/**inprivate** tab: 
from the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-open:~:text=You%20can%20also%20set%20process.env.BROWSER_ARGS%20to%20pass%20additional%20arguments%20(e.g.%20%2D%2Dincognito).) : 

 " You can also set `process.env.BROWSER_ARGS` to pass additional arguments (e.g. --incognito)."